# Push maven project from Bamboo to Nexus

Tags: maven, nexus, bamboo

I need to set-up plan to push maven project from Bamboo to Nexus. I can connect to GitHub from bamboo, but when I'm running the plan, I'm getting:

```
Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized.
```

I have all plugins configured in my POM, but I'm guessing, I'm not able to pass some credentials for Nexus from maven `settings.xml`

How can I pass this Nexus credentials to Bamboo?

Comment: Are you sure you added the necessary usernames/passwords to the settings.xml?

Comment: Yes, they are correct. Where should I place this `settings.xml` in project?

Comment: You don't place it in the project, but in the `.m2` directory of the maven installation.

Comment: I have no admin rights for bamboo, I'm only admin of my Project and Build Plan, so everything should be configured on Plan level

Comment: Usually, the admin would configure Maven correctly, so that it can deploy to Nexus. If this is not possible, you can explicitly specify a settings.xml by using the `-s` parameter.

Comment: and where should I place this file?

Comment: It is unusual to place it in the project, so there is no standard place. Just choose one.

Comment: Ok, I was able to solve a problem, by creating separate repository in source control, only with `settings.xml`, and add additional source code checkout for this file